# Nodejs call shellscript or use native node modules?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node. I have the following requirement that can be broken down into three different parts
1) Pure nodejs: Get the IP and User info
2) SSH to a remote server with a private key and list down the directories

What is the best way to do it? I have thought of calling a shell script with child_process for the second step. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js module, [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), is probably what I would use.